# Как сделать единый класс для всех решений в Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Пишу приложение на Xamarin.Forms. Хотел создать локальные уведомления и нашел следующие ссылки:

[для iOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/local-notifications-in-ios) 

[для Android](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications)

Хотел бы узнать, как можно их объединить в единый класс, который потом можно использовать в дальнейшем в решении Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Вы можете воспользоваться данной библиотекой: https://github.com/tmt242001/Plugin.LocalNotification

Comment: @Emigrant спасибо за ссылку, эта библиотека уведомлений оказалось получше той, которую я рассматривал